# evaluation of list comprehensions in python

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

In trying to use a list comprehension to make a list given a conditional, I see the following:

```
In [1]: mydicts = [{'foo':'val1'},{'foo':''}]

In [2]: mylist = [d for d in mydicts if d['foo']]

In [3]: mylist
Out[3]: [{'foo': 'val1'}]

In [4]: mydicts[1]['foo'] = 'val2'

In [5]: mydicts
Out[5]: [{'foo': 'val1'}, {'foo': 'val2'}]

In [6]: mylist
Out[6]: [{'foo': 'val1'}]
```

I've been reading the docs to try and understand this but have come up with nothing so far, so I'll ask my question here: why is it that `mylist` never includes `{'foo': 'val2'}` even though the reference in the list comprehension points to `mydict`, which by `In [6]` contains `{'foo': 'val2'}`? Is this because Python eagerly evaluates list comprehensions? Or is the lazy/eager dichotomy totally irrelevant to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused about what list comprehensions do.

When you do this:

```
[d for d in mydicts if d['foo']]
```

That evaluates to a new list. So, when you do this:

```
mylist = [d for d in mydicts if d['foo']]
```

You're assigning that list as the value of `mylist`. You can see this very easily:

```
assert type(mylist) == list
```

You're not assigning "a list comprehension" that gets reevaluated every time to `mylist`. There are no magic values in Python that get reevaluated every time. (You can *fake* them by, e.g., creating a `class` with a `@property`, but that's not really an exception; it's the expression `myobj.myprop` that's being reevaluated, not `myprop` itself.)

---

In fact, `mylist = [d for d in mydicts if d['foo']]` is basically the same `mylist = [1, 2, 3]`.* In both cases, you're creating a new list, and assigning it to `mylist`. You wouldn't expect the second one to re-evaluate `[1, 2, 3]` each time (otherwise, doing `mylist[0] = 0` wouldn't do much good, because as soon as you try to view `mylist` you'd be getting a new, pristine list!). The same is true here.

* In Python 3.x, they aren't just *basically* the same; they're both just different types of list displays. In 2.x, it's a bit more murky, and they just happen to both evaluate to new list objects.

Answer (score 8):

There's no lazy evaluation of lists in Python. List comprehensions simply create a new list. If you want "lazy" evaluation, use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead.

```
my_generator_expression = (d for d in mydicts if d['foo']) # note parentheses
mydicts[1]['foo'] = 'val2'
print(my_generator_expression) # >>> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000>
for d in my_generator_expression:
    print(d) # >>> {'foo': 'val1'}
             # >>> {'foo': 'val2'}
```

Note that generators differ from lists in several important ways. Perhaps the most notable is that once you iterate over them, they are exhausted, so they're best to use if you only need the data they contain once.

Comment: I don't think this is what he's after. He's already printing out all of the values; changing the source list and printing out all of the properties again will just give him nothing, because he's already exhausted the iterator.

Comment: @abarnert I took his console output to be simply a convenient way to try several different things in an example-able format, but I'll make a note of the non-reusability of generators as well.

Answer (score 0):

`mylist` contains the result of a previous list comprehension evaluation, it won't magically updated just because you update a variable that was used for its computation.